# Kendo UI Angular Upload / Kendo Grid integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

Ok, here are the Versions:

- Kendo UI v2014.3.1119
- AngularJS v1.3.6
- jQuery v@1.8.1 jquery.com

The issue is the following: I have a kendo upload that should populate a grid after a excel file is read. I'm using Kendo UI Angular Directives. Here are some key pieces of code:

**Upload Html**

```
 <input name="files"
               type="file"
               kendo-upload
               k-async="{ saveUrl: '{{dialogOptions.ImportUrl}}', autoUpload: false, batch: true }"
               k-options="{localization: {uploadSelectedFiles: '{{messages.Global_Button_Import}}'}}"
               k-error="onImportError"
               k-select="onSelect"
               k-success="onImportSuccess" k-multiple="false" />
```

**Grid Html**

```
 <div kendo-grid="grid" k-options="gridOptions" k-ng-delay="gridOptions" k-rebind="gridOptions" >
        </div>
```

**Key pieces on the controller**

```
angular.module('global').controller('ImportResultsController', [
'$scope', 'BaseApi', 'ImportResultsService', 'GridUtil', '$http', '$q', '$timeout',
function ($scope, BaseApi, ImportResultsService, GridUtil, $http, $q, $timeout) {


$scope.gridOptions;
    $scope.gridColumns;
    $scope.results = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);

//These columns should come from the server, right now are harcoded

$scope.getGridColumns = function () {
        $scope.gridColumns = [
               { field: "Zone", width: 70, title: "Zone", template: "" },
               { field: "Aisle", width: 70, title: "Aisle", template: "" },
               { field: "Rack", width: 70, title: "Rack", template: "" },
               { field: "Shelf", width: 70, title: "Shelf", template: "" },
               { field: "Bin", width: 70, title: "Bin", template: "" },
               //{ field: "DateEffectiveFrom", width: 70, title: "Date" },
               { field: "BinStatus", width: 70, title: "BinStatus", template: "" }
        ];
    }


$scope.getClientGridOptions = function(columns,  data, pageSize) {

    var gridOptions = {
        sortable: true,
        dataSource: {
            data: data,
            pageSize: pageSize
        },
        selectable: 'row',
        columns: columns,
        pageable: {
            pageSize: pageSize,
            refresh: false,                
            pageSizes: [10, 20, 30],
            messages: $.kendoMessages
        },
    };

    return gridOptions
}

$scope.onImportSuccess = function (e) {
        var files = e.files;

        if (e.operation == "upload") {
            console.log(files);
            if (e.XMLHttpRequest.response != "") {
                var model = $.parseJSON(e.XMLHttpRequest.response); //This step does not fail, model return is always filled
                $scope.results = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);

                for (var i = 0; i < model.Data.length; i++) {
                    $scope.results.push(model.Data[i]);
                }

                $scope.gridOptions = $scope.getClientGridOptions($scope.gridColumns, $scope.results, 10);
                //$scope.grid.dataSource.data($scope.results); //This does not work

                $scope.isDataReady = true;

               // $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data($scope.results) //This does not work                  
               // $scope.grid.refresh(); //This does not work
                $scope.$apply()



            }               

        }                  

    }

}]);
```

The issues vary. Sometimes I get the data bound until the second uploaded file, and after the third time, I start receiving 'Cannot read property 'get' of undefined ' errors. When this second error happens, the bind works, but the error is present. Do you have any idea of what could it be?

In case of you need the url for the upload, here's the method. Is an MVC .net application. Since I always get the response correctly and it's a Json Array, I believe there's no issue there, but here's anyways.

```
dialogOptions.ImportUrl = LoadImportedBinLocations
```

**MVC Controller**

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadImportedBinLocations(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        bool success = false;

        var importHistory = new PartsImportHistory();
        List<dynamic> data = null;
        try
        {
            //int divisor = 0;
            //var y = 5 / divisor;

            if (files != null)
            {
                using (var client = new ServiceLocator<IPartsService>())
                {
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        bool isExcelFile = extension == ".xls" || extension == ".xlsx";

                        if (isExcelFile)
                        {
                            var filePath = UploadAttachment(file);

                            //importHistory = client.Service.SavePartsImportHistory(new PartsImportHistory
                            //{
                            //    CreatedByName = CurrentContext.UserDisplayName,
                            //    CreatedByUserID = CurrentContext.UserId,
                            //    PartsImportStatus = (int)DMSModel.EnumStore.PartsImportStatus.InProgress,
                            //    FilePath = filePath
                            //});
                            data = new List<dynamic> 
                                { 
                                    new { Zone = "A", Aisle = "02", Rack = "06", Shelf = "20", Bin = "D", DateEffectiveFrom = DateTime.UtcNow, BinStatus = "Unblocked", IsValid= true, ImportError ="" },
                                    new { Zone = "B", Aisle = "02", Rack = "06", Shelf = "10", Bin = "D", DateEffectiveFrom = DateTime.UtcNow, BinStatus = "Blocked", IsValid=false, ImportError="Zone does not Exist" }
                                };

                            success = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception(WarpDMS.Globalization.Resources.PartsAdmin_ImportParts_ErrorFileFormat);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return Json(new { success = success, Data = data });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(ex.Message ?? ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private string UploadAttachment(HttpPostedFileBase item)
    {
        string path = string.Empty;
        string internalFileName = string.Empty;
        string basePath = ConfigManager.ATTACHMENTS_PATH;

        if (item != null && item.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            internalFileName = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), System.IO.Path.GetExtension(item.FileName));
            path = Path.Combine(basePath, internalFileName);

            item.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return Path.Combine(basePath, internalFileName).Replace('\\', '/');
    }
```